# Cómo incluir un namespace automáticamente al crear nuevas clases C# desde Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespace

Cuando creas una nueva clase C# en Visual Studio, por defecto ya incluye algunos namespaces estándar. Por ejemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Estoy buscando la forma de que, por defecto, también se incluya un namespace adicional (ejemplo: `Extensions`) donde se encuentra una clase que yo hice que tiene varios métodos de extensión. Por ejemplo, quisiera que al crear una clase nueva, que de una vez quedara de la siguiente forma:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Extensiones; // namespace adicional
```

¿Cómo se puede lograr esto?

Comment: Puedes mostrar un simple ejemplo? No esta muy claro lo que preguntas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta precisa depende de la versión de Visual Studio que usas, porque cada versión tiene sus peculiaridades en cuanto a donde se encuentran los archivos instalados con Visual Studio.

Pero tomando mi instalación de Visual Studio como ejemplo, en el path siguiente se encuentra el template que Visual Studio usa cuando creas una nueva clase en C#:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

Contenido en mi instalación:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

Simplemente edita `Class.cs` y agrega la sentencia `using` que deseas.

Nuevamente, si tienes una versión diferente de Visual Studio, tendrás que ajustar un poco el path para encontrar el archivo `Class.cs`, pero debería ser muy parecido al ejemplo que te dejé.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta me fue de mucha ayuda! Finalmente agregue una libreria de extension para el netFramework como lo detallan aqui y la directiva using en el template para visual studio :) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee722096.aspx